# Instantiating Helpers in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, helper, dependency-injection

The latest builds of Magento 2 have done away with the `Mage` class.  This mean we've lost the `Mage::helper` method.

Is there a replacement technique (helper factory?) for instantiating helpers in Magento 2?  Or are we expected to use the new Object manager class, and just instantiate the helper as a  singleton/cached object with `get` (vs. `create`)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I see you came to right solution, just want to summarize.

Constructor injection should be used to retrieve helper (or any other instance) in whatever class you need:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Core\Helper\Data $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function doSmth()
    {
        $this->helper->someMethod();
    }
}
```

Notice that **no phpDoc comments are required**, Magento will read constructor signature directly to figure out what dependencies are required.

\Magento\Core\Helper\Factory should be used only in those rare cases when you have to call a lot of multiple helpers, or you don't know exactly which one you need.

Usage of Object Manager directly is **strictly discouraged**. So please avoid using:

```
\Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance()
```

It's there only for serialization/deserialization.

Comment: do not use static as it can't be tested with PHP unit and yes it is discouraged. 
All M2 dependencies are done through the constructor, and managed by the Object Manager internally, and will retrieve it as Singleton



Also do not use _ to indicate a property visibility, All M2 naming should use the camecase

Comment: @Anton Kril if we use `helper` in template, like `$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')`, it follows the best practice?

Comment: No, it does not. Templates should only reference blocks. Helpers should be avoided

Answer (score 10):

It looks like Magento's encouraging folks to use their [new automatic dependency injection](http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/66355728727/instantiating-and-injecting-helpers-in-magento-2) system to get helpers and models into objects via the object's constructor.

The short version?  If you have an object that's instantiated by the object manager, <s>**and** decorate a constructor with a PHPDoc `@param`</s>, **and** the parameters has a proper type hint set, the object manager will automatically instantiate the helper (or, I believe, other objects) for you.

For example, the following constructor would inject a a core data helper into the object.

```
/**
* @param \Magento\Core\Helper\Data $coreData
*/        
public function __construct(\Magento\Core\Helper\Data $coreData)
{
    $this->_coreHelper = $coreData;            
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - great sleuthing; was not totally obvious to me even after a lot of digging.

Comment: OK ...now my head hurts...a lot. You mean that we are supposed to use PHPDoc to "write" code? This is madness. I quit.

Comment: @Marius hahaha this is not that uncommon - Alan's blog explains it to some extent.

Comment: @philwinkle. I've read his article. Very interesting, but I still say this is madness. Call me old fashioned, but "back in my days" code was code and comments were those things that almost nobody bothered to write.

Comment: Oh...and by the way. +1. Good question & nice answer.

Comment: @Marius The second someone implements a commenting system for doc blocks I'm running for the hills.

Comment: @Marius See the new best answer — looks like I jumped the gun on the doc block stuff.

Comment: @AlanStorm. Yeah I saw the answer. Please never scare me like that again.

Answer (score 9):

Apart from all above answers, if you have to use helper in phtml template you can simply do like this:

```
$this->helper('[Vendor]\[Module]\Helper\[Helper Name]');
```

I hope it is helpful if somebody didn't know it before ;)

Answer (score 6):

The way that helpers are instantiated (at least for the new Backend (~dev50) module) are via a helperFactory:

```
/**
 * Return helper object
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return \Magento\Core\Helper\AbstractHelper
 */
public function helper($name)
{
    return $this->_helperFactory->get($name);
}
```

Which is essentially just a specialized type of a model factory. E.g: Magento\Core\Block\Context line 143 (dev50) as part of the constructor:

```
\Magento\Core\Model\Factory\Helper $helperFactory
```

The helper factory will return the requested model based on the class name and ensure that it is an `instanceof` the helper abstract class:

```
/**
 * Get helper singleton
 *
 * @param string $className
 * @param array $arguments
 * @return \Magento\Core\Helper\AbstractHelper
 * @throws \LogicException
 */
public function get($className, array $arguments = array())
{
    $className = str_replace('_', '\\', $className);
    /* Default helper class for a module */
    if (strpos($className, '\Helper\\') === false) {
        $className .= '\Helper\Data';
    }

    $helper = $this->_objectManager->get($className, $arguments);

    if (false === ($helper instanceof \Magento\Core\Helper\AbstractHelper)) {
        throw new \LogicException(
            $className . ' doesn\'t extends Magento\App\Helper'
        );
    }

    return $helper;
}
```

**If you were to implement this yourself** it seems Magento core is loading it in one of two ways:

Roll your own factory:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$helperFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Core\Model\Factory\Helper');
$helper = $helperFactory->get('\PulseStorm\Commercebug\Helper\Data');
```

Or just grab it directly:

```
$helper = \Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Core\Helper\Data');
```

Comment: +1 for useful information, but would you want to instantiate the factory directly like that?  Or should a single helper factory be instantiated with the Object Manager as a cached class with `get`?

Comment: It's not totally clear, because the helper factory is inherited from \Mage\Core\Block\Abstract -- I think the intention is provide your own helper factory. It does *not* look like they're intentionally creating a singleton for the factory, though.

Comment: Sounds like I need/the best source is to trace how _helperFactory is injected into those objects and see how the core team instantiates it.

Comment: My simplification summary is incorrect as well as the constructor requires an instance of ObjectManager. I will edit momentarily.

Comment: See edit. It should work - hard to determine at this moment because my cli shell environment isn't loading the store config instance as expected. This should be enough to get you on the right track, though.

Comment: Good enough for government work, but it looks like Magento is encouraging people to use their auto dependency injection for this sort of thing. http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/66355728727/instantiating-and-injecting-helpers-in-magento-2

Comment: Your tumblr on the new automatic DI kind of blew my mind - you should create it as a new answer and mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: I think \Magento\Core\Model namespace doesn't exist. I used \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance() instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Xx\Xx\Helper\Xx');
```

Comment: Usage of Object Manager directly is strictly discouraged.

Comment: @sv3n could you please explain, what's the reason?. Thanks.

Comment: Better use dependency injections instead ... answered here for example ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142352/magento-2-how-to-use-objectmanager-class-object