# Magento2 -How to get data from system configuration

Tags: magento2, system.xml

Fields added through the system.xml and default values populated with config.xml, how do we fetch the data in Magento2

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Implementing in a class,

```
class Dummy 
{
   /**
   * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
   */
   protected $scopeConfig;

   /**
   * Recipient email config path
   */
   const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'contact/email/recipient_email';

   public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
   {
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
   }

   /**
   * Sample function returning config value
   **/

  public function getReceipentEmail() {
     $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

     return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope);


     }
}
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig) -- there should be "\" preceding  "Magento"

Comment: Just a hint: if you define methods which access config values in an helper class (extending `\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper`) you will already have the `$this->scopeConfig` object without any need to inject it

Comment: @AlessandroRonchi is there a list of all objects available in extended abstract helper classes somewhere?

Comment: @paj as far as I know, you have to recursively look at constructor's dependencies of super classes;

Answer (score 17):

Create a function for getting configuration values in your custom module's helper.

```
public function getConfig($config_path)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $config_path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
}
```

and call anywhere you want for example in test.phtml

```
$moduleStatus = $this->helper('Customvendorname\Custommodulename\Helper\Data')->getConfig('sectionid/groupid/fieldid');
```

In block and helper call like this:

```
 $this->_objectManager->create('Customvendorname\Custommodulename\Helper\Data')->getConfig('sectionid/groupid/fieldid');
```

Note: construct Object Manager on class constructor or directly use as

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->create('Customvendorname\Custommodulename\Helper\Data')->getConfig('sectionid/groupid/fieldid');
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use the following code to get the value from the core_config table

**Edit:**

Create an instance of ScopeConfigInterface class using object manager

```
   $scopeConfig = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
```

Then
By using the scopeConfig object get the config value

```
    $configPath = $sectionId.'/'.$groupId.'/'.$fieldId;
    $value =  $scopeConfig->getValue(
        $configPath,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
```

Comment: even if it works, the use of objectManager to instantiate classes is highly discouraged. The correct approach is to use dependency injection.

Comment: i guess that decreases the chance of a rewrite.

Comment: @Marius  - why is magento using $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category') in magento2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category.php

Comment: That one didn't get refactored yet. Check this for more details http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/28617/146

Comment: okie cool makes sense

Answer (score 6):

I have done like this, I have created a helper function in Data.php file

```
public function getConfig($config_path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                $config_path,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                );
    }
```

Then i have called one single line in the phtml file.

```
$required_loc = $this->helper('Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data')->getConfig('sectionid/groupid/fieldid');
```