# magento 2 add field system config

Tags: magento2, system.xml, system-config

I am new in Magento 2. I want to add text field in `Store > Configuration` which store HTML code.

This HTML code will display in Frontend.

eg. I want to add note for custom shipping method this note field contain HTML code with proper HTML tag. This note is display after Shipping method in frontend.
If I add `<h3> Hello </h3>` than it display proper code with effect of HTML tag. Not Display like `<h3> Hello </h3>` in frontend.

Following system.xml

```
        <group id="flatrate1" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
              <label>Flat Rate 1</label>
              <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Flat Rate 1</label>
                  <source_model>Namespace\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable</source_model>
              </field>
              <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                  <label>Method Name</label>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                  <label>Title</label>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="type" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Type</label>
                  <source_model>Namespace\Multiflatrate\Model\Config\Source\Method</source_model>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="price" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Price</label>
                  <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="handling_type" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Calculate Handling Fee</label>
                  <source_model>Namespace\Multiflatrate\Model\Config\Source\HandlingType</source_model>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="handling_fee" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="7" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Handling Fee</label>
                  <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="sallowspecific" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="8" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                  <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                  <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="9" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                  <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                  <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="showmethod" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
                  <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="specificerrmsg" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                  <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="max_amount" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="13" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Maximum Order Amount For Free Shipping</label>
                  <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="min_amount" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="14" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Minimum Order Amount For Free Shipping</label>
                  <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
              <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="HTML" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="15" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Sort Order</label>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>

              <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="101" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                  <label>Display Text</label>
                  <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
              </field>

          </group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code :

```
 <field id="shipnote" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                  <label>Ship note</label>
                  <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
</field>
```

After this code:

```
   <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                  <label>Title</label>
                  <depends><field id="active">1</field></depends>
              </field>
```

[For get the config text use below code or click on this link.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108817)

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('section_id/group_id/field_id', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

[For more detail see here](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html) and [Here](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/10/magento2-system-xml/)

Comment: thanks for answer but I dont want like this I update my qustion you can check.

Comment: For adding "text field" in backend it will help you. Do you want Additional shipping block after shipping method  ?

Comment: Yes I want to Add new text field in backend after Shipping Method Title Field

Comment: Have you created any custom shipping module if yes. then please post your code.

Comment: I post system.xml code

Comment: I have updated the code please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51118/discussion-between-new-bee-in-magento-and-arunendra).