# Magento2 : Retrieve Multiselect Values in system.xml

Tags: magento2, module, custom, system.xml

I have created a system.xml file with a multiselect type field somewhere in my admin system config. I just want to know on how to retrieve the selected values in that field?

Comment: I found the solution by using Mage::getStoreConfig(section_group_field path)

Comment: https://bit.ly/2w7H6y2 using link got all the multiselect attribute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define `<source_model>` in `system.xml`:

```xml
    <field id="Moduleposition" translate="Module" type="multiselect" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Module Position</label>
        <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\ConfigOption</source_model>
    </field>
```

Now create `ConfigOption.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;


class ConfigOption implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Top Right')],
            ['value' => '2', 'label' => __('Top Left')],
            ['value' => '3', 'label' => __('Middle Right')],
            ['value' => '4', 'label' => __('Middle')],
            ['value' => '5', 'label' => __('Middle Left')],
            ['value' => '6', 'label' => __('Bottom Right')],
            ['value' => '7', 'label' => __('Bottom Left')]
        ];
    }
}
```

You will get multiselect value in string with `value1,value2,value3` format.

You can use explode() function to convert it into array like this

```php
    $value = explode(',', $multiSelectValue);
```

For more info about how you can get system.xml config value refer this question

[Magento2 -How to get data from system configuration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87789/magento2-how-to-get-data-from-system-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Just like all the other values from your system.xml. The result will be a string with comma separated values. So you have explode the string and have an array for better handling like

```
$miltiselectValues = explode(',', $configValue);
```