# Magento 2 | get value from system.xml

Tags: magento2, configuration

I have created a menu in the configuration menu.

> system.xml:

I have an observer and I want to get the values of those two fields.

How can I do that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check that link you will get answer of your question by help of this .
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87789/magento2-how-to-get-data-from-system-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this below code in your observer :

```
protected $scopeConfig;

const XML_PATH_CREDIT_CARD = 'uv_email/general/uv_email_kredit';
const XML_PATH_SALES_TEAM = 'uv_email/general/uv_email_vertrieb';

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ......
) {
    ......
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ......
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    $credit_card_value = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_CREDIT_CARD, $storeScope);
    $sales_team_value = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_SALES_TEAM, $storeScope);
}
```

Comment: Use this updated answer.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to UO\CheckCartSpecialProducts\Observer\AfterPurchaseObserver::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface, none given,

Comment: Remove var/generation or generated/ folder after add this code.

Comment: Go to core_config_data table in database. Then, search "uv_email/general/uv_email_kredit" in path column and check value is available or not.