# Get Payment method API keys in controller from admin sales->configuration->payment-methods?

Tags: magento2

[image]

I am integrating a custom payment module. I need to get the API keys in my controller. If possible in JS file also.

**My Controller** where I need to get the config values.

```
<?php
namespace vendorName\moduleName\Controller\Index;

class GetPrice extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $customHelper;

    public function __construct( 
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $customHelper 
    ) {    
        $this->customHelper = $customHelper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){
        echo $this->customHelper->getConfig("payment/title/cmc_api_key");
    }
}
```

**system.xml**

```
    <section id="payment" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="1000" translate="label">
        <group id="mypay" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
            <label>MyPay</label>
                <field id="title" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="20" translate="label" type="text">
                <label>Title</label>
            </field>
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You can get configuration value like - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87789/magento2-how-to-get-data-from-system-configuration

Comment: Is that working or not?

Comment: no It is not working :(

Comment: Please share your `system.xml` which is used to create a configuration field.

Comment: ` <section id="payment" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="1000" translate="label">
   <group id="mypay" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
   
    <field id="title" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1"

Comment: update it in your question

Comment: @Ranganathan i have updated the system.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101015/discussion-between-ranganathan-and-garry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one `Helper` and in that helper you can create one function there by using that function you can get config value by passing only key of your configuration everywhere in Blocks, Controllers and Model etc..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getConfig($configPath)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $configPath,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Now you just need to inject this Helper class in your Controller like this

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data as Helper;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_helper;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Helper $helper
    ){
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){
        echo $this->_helper->getConfig("sectionid/groupid/fieldid");
    }
}
```

And in `phtml` you can get config value like this..

```
$test = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getConfig('sectionid/groupid/fieldid');
```

You can download reference module [here](https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-magehelper-magento2). I've added code in this module how you can access config data in your **JS** file in this module.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Any way for including key config in JS?

Comment: I've to use this in ajax controller. Can i use it like this?
`public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,  \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $customHelper)
    {
  $this->customHelper = $customHelper;
        return parent::__construct($context, $this->customHelper);
    }`

Comment: You can use like this

Comment: public function __construct(
 \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
 \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $customHelper
) { 
 $this->customHelper = $customHelper;
 parent::__construct($context); 
}

Comment: I am getting Error here when i request price with **AJAX**.
`jquery.js:10260 POST http://127.0.0.1/magento3/modulename/Index/GetPrice 500 (Internal Server Error)`
Here Is my section 

`<section id="payment" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="1000" translate="label">`

**Group**
 `<group id="mynewgroup" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">`

**FieldID**
`<field id="title" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="20" translate="label" type="text">`

Comment: This controller works okay, If i remove this code... how can i resolve this???

Comment: Remove generated folder and try

Comment: @RakeshVarma I am new to magento, may i know which generated folder?

Comment: @Garry, generated folder is available on Magento Root directory

Comment: You can rename that from generated to generated1 and try to run setup upgrade

Comment: Whenever you will change anything in construct please run setup:di:compile command

Comment: This is my code. 
I've
 renamed the generated folder. then i run this command
1)  php bin/magento setup:di:compile
2)  php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3)  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
**ERROR**
`POST http://127.0.0.1/magento3/iostpaymagento/Index/GetPrice 500 (Internal Server Error)`
**This is my code**
`protected $customHelper;


  public function __construct( 
         \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
         \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $customHelper ) 
   {

     $this->customHelper = $customHelper;
     parent::__construct($context);
   } `

Comment: Can you please update your file code in your question please ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya File updated. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101013/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-garry).

Answer (score 1):

Get a value in your controller like, According to your `system.xml` you given wrong path, use `$configPath` variable path to get your configuration

```
<?php
namespace vendorName\moduleName\Controller\Index;

class GetPrice extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct( 
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {    
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){
        $configPath = 'payment/mypay/title';
        echo $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                  $configPath,
                  \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
             );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get value in JS file you can use the below code.

In your module `etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="api_key" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ApiKeyConfigProvider</item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
</config>
```

and in your `ApiKeyConfigProvider.php` add below code.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
class ApiKeyConfigProvider implements \Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface
{
   public function getConfig()
   {
       $output['api_key'] = 'your_api_key';
       return $output;
   }
}
```

You can access above api key in js file like this.

```
window.checkoutConfig.api_key
```

Comment: Did the same. but it shows error of  `undefined`. :(

Comment: undefined of what?

Comment: I tried this
https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-magehelper-magento2

this is working correct, Please have a look

Comment: You have overridden the class please check my `di.xml` code.