# Correct way of getting helper in template of custom block

Tags: magento2, template, helper, dependency-injection

What is the correct way of getting a helper in a template file of a custom block?

In `Magento_Search` module there is a block:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
        name="top.search" 
        as="topSearch" 
        template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" 
    />
</referenceContainer>
```

In the `form.mini.phtml` template I found this way of getting helper object:

```
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Search\Helper\Data');
```

I read in many tutorials that I should inject an instance of the helper in the constructor `__construct()` of the block. This can be found in dozens of Magento template files. But in some templates helpers are retrieved with `$this->helper(...)` method.

Just like in the `top.search` block from my example. It is an instance of the generic `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class so probably that's why the helper had to be retrieved this way (because we can't inject it in the constructor).

#### 1.

So can I use this `$this->helper(...)` method in my custom blocks instead of injecting helpers through constructor? Or is it a bad practice and it should be avoided? It's less code and more convenient.

#### 2.

Where is that `helper` method implemented? I couldn't find it in the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class nor in its parent classes.

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74526/magento-2-accessing-a-helper-without-using-constructor-injection

Answer (score 4):

The way to inject a helper into the `Template` model via DI (Dependency Injection) is to:

1. Extend the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` block with your own (eg: `class MyBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`)
2. Then in the `MyBlock` constructor, inject your Helper:

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * @var \Magento\Search\Helper\Data $helper
    */
   protected $helper;

   public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
     \Magento\Search\Helper\Data $helper,
     array $data = []
   ) {
       $this->helper = $helper;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }
   ```
3. Then add a getter method to `MyBlock`:

   ```
   <?php
   function getDataHelper() {
       return $this->helper;
   }
   ```
4. Define your block to use the new MyBlock you created (instead of `Template`):

   ```
   <block class="Your\ModuleBlocks\MyBlock" 
     name="top.search" 
     as="topSearch" 
     template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" 
    />
   ```
5. Then in your block `.pthml` template you can access the helper this way:

   ```
   <?php $block->getDataHelper() ?>
   ```

It's certainly easier to just call `$this->helper()` in the `.phtml` template.

As for part 2 of your question, `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` is the `$block` object in your `.phtml` template, and you are correct: it does not have the `helper()` method.

However, the `$this` object in a `.phtml` template is the `Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php` object, which does have that method (as noted in another answer).

(Using this `helper()` method requires that your helper extend the `Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper` class, it should be noted.)

Comment: This is valuable, thanks for the detailed explanation about $block and $this

Answer (score 1):

1. Most of the developers will tell you it is not convenient. Due to the body of function helper. It returns something like this: ObjectManager->get(...) (Singleton).
2. In Magento 2.1.1 it is located in: vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php  ~Line: 120
3. Nevertheless until Magento will stop using this function in phtml- files, i will do so.

Answer (score 1):

View helpers should be simple and easy to use methods, which can be used in any template, without a need to create a custom block for this purpose - for me it is very convenient.