# Magento 2 : How to use objectManager class object?

Tags: magento2, object-manager

I am little bit confuse, how to use object manager.
I have checked [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly) answer but not getting satisfied answer.

Always we are recommending that never use objectManager like `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()`.

Instead of use this :

```
public function __construct(
   ...
   \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
   ...
) 
{
   ...
   $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
   ...
}
```

But when we are using this in any **plugin file** or **any custom module file**, we are getting error or its not working. But in case of direct method we are getting solution.

Is there any proper definition, where we have to use direct method of `objectManager` and where we have to use `ObjectManagerInterface` ?

Actually when I am trying to get objectManager object in my custom module file I am getting some error and its not working. and with the help of direct method getting proper solution.

Comment: Don't use the object manager directly: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/117098/2380

Comment: Never use object manager directly use it in __construct and To solve error you need to delete generation file

Answer (score 4):

This is a misconception, your code should not be aware of the object manager **at all**. You add the classes that you actually need in the constructor.

So instead of

```
ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Foo\Bar::class)
```

you use

```
__construct(\Foo\Bar $foobar)
{
    $this->foobar = $foobar
}
```

And if you need to create new instances, instead of

```
ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(\Foo\Bar::class)
```

you use a factory:

```
__construct(\Foo\BeerFactory $foobeerFactory)
{
    $this->foobeerFactory = $foobeerFactory;
}

...

$this->foobeerFactory->create()
```